# Error in flowplayer flash : 201, unable to load stream or clip, connection failed

Tags: google-chrome, flowplayer

I am getting 201, unable to load stream or clip, connection failed…
its coming only in chrome, but when i play it chrome incognito window, it plays nicely. and in all browsers, it is running . so what may be the problem, kindly help.